# program doesn't run(getting RUN FINISHED Segmentation fault core dumped)

Tags: c, struct

I've been tried to make working a program, the compiler don't show me neither warnings nor errors, just shows me RUN FINISHED Segmentation fault core dumped, I guess it has something to do with assignment of the values to the pointers but I didn't find the error, Could you help me?

Struct person

```
#ifndef PERSONSTRUCT_H
#define PERSONSTRUCT_H
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    int edad;
    char nombre[100];
}persona;

persona *getNodoPerson();
void setEdad(int, persona *);
void setNombre(char *, persona *);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

struct nodo

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#ifndef LISTASIMPLEMENLAZADA_H
#define LISTASIMPLEMENLAZADA_H
#include "PersonStruct.h"

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    struct nodo{
        struct nodo *siguiente;
        persona *person;
    };

    typedef struct nodo *ptrNodo;
    typedef struct nodo *lista;

    void freeNode(ptrNodo);
    ptrNodo getNodo();
    int empty(lista);
    ptrNodo buscar(char[],int, lista);
    int contar(lista);
    void addAtEnd(char *, int, lista);
    void del(lista,char *,int);
    void imprimirDatos(lista);
    int getPos(lista, persona *);
    lista getLista();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Functions for struct nodo

```
#include "ListaSimplemEnlazada.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Esta funcion elimina de memoria el nodo enviado 
void freeNode(ptrNodo p)
{
    free(p);
}

//Esta funcion crea el espacio de memoria para un nodo
ptrNodo getNodo()
{
    ptrNodo p;
    p=(ptrNodo)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    return p;
}

lista getLista()
{
    lista l;
    l=(lista)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    l->person=NULL;
    return l;
}

//Esta funcion revisa si una lista esta vacia;
int empty(lista l)
{
    int x;
    if(l->siguiente==NULL)
    {
        x=TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        x=FALSE;
    }

    return x;
}

//Esta funcion cuenta el numero de elementos que tiene una lista enlazada
int contar(lista l)
{
    int cont=0;
    ptrNodo aux=getNodo();
    aux=l->siguiente;
    while(aux!=NULL)
    {
        aux=aux->siguiente;
        cont++;
    }
    return cont;
}

//Esta funcion busca en la lista especificada, el nodo en el que se encuentra la estructura se encuentra especificada
//si la estructura es encontrada, devuelve un puntero al nodo donde esta la estructura 
//si no devuelve un puntero nulo
ptrNodo buscar(char *nom,int age, lista l)
{
    ptrNodo aux=getNodo(),retorno=getNodo();
    retorno=NULL;
    if(!empty(l))
    {
        aux=l->siguiente;
        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            if ((aux->person->edad==age) && (strcmp(aux->person->nombre,nom)==0))
            {
                retorno=aux;
                break;
            }
            aux=aux->siguiente;
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}

//Ingresa un nodo al final de la lista, si la lista es vacia, lo ingresa como el primer elemento de la lista
void addAtEnd(char *nombre,int age,lista l)
{
    ptrNodo aux1=getNodo(),aux2=getNodo();
    aux2->person->edad=age;
    strcpy(aux2->person->nombre,nombre);
    aux2->siguiente=NULL;
    if(!empty(l))
    {
        aux1=buscar(nombre,age,l);
        if(aux1==NULL)
        {
            aux1=l->siguiente;
            while(aux1!=NULL)
            {
                aux1=aux1->siguiente;
            }
            aux1->siguiente=aux2;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("El valor ya se encuentra en la lista");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        l->siguiente=aux2;
    }

}

//Envia la posicion numerica del nodo en la lista, retornara 0 si no encuentra el nodo
int getPos(lista l, persona *p)
{
    ptrNodo aux=getNodo();
    int x=0;
    if(!empty(l))
    {
        aux=buscar(p->nombre,p->edad,l);
        if(aux!=NULL)
        {
            aux=l->siguiente;
            while(aux->person->edad==p->edad && (strcmp(aux->person->nombre,p->nombre)==0))
            {
                x++;
                aux=aux->siguiente;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}

//Este metodo elimina el valor de lista
void del(lista l,char *nom,int age)
{
    ptrNodo aux1=getNodo(),aux2=getNodo();
    int x,i;
    if(!empty(l))
    {
            aux1=buscar(nom,age,l);
            if(aux1!=NULL)
            {
                x=getPos(l,aux1->person);
                aux2=l->siguiente;
                for(i=1;i<=(x-1);i++)
                {
                    aux2=aux2->siguiente;
                }
                aux2->siguiente=aux1->siguiente;
                printf("\nLa persona %s y edad %d",aux1->person->nombre,aux1->person->edad);
                freeNode(aux1);
            }
     }
}

void imprimirDatos(lista l)
{
    ptrNodo aux=getNodo();
    int i=1;
    if(!empty(l))
    {
        aux=l->siguiente;
        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\nLa persona numero %d con \tNombre:%s y edad:%d",i,aux->person->nombre,aux->person->edad);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ListaSimplemEnlazada.h"
#include "PersonStruct.h"

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    argc=argc;
    argv=argv;

    char *nombres[5]={"Alberto", "Manuel","Enrique","Josue","Ronald"};
    int edad[5]={25,39,45,12,21};
    int i;
    lista l=getLista();
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        addAtEnd(nombres[i],edad[i],l);
    }
    imprimirDatos(l);
    del(l,nombres[0],edad[0]);
    imprimirDatos(l 
             );

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

sorry for the big amount of code but perhaps you will need it for understanding what I've done wrong with my program

Comment: Did you try using a debugger, say `gdb`?

Comment: Also, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you have `argc=argc;
    argv=argv;` in `main`?

Comment: Sorry, i already did it, i got a SIGSEGV signal at this line `aux2->person->edad=age;` in the function `addAtEnd` in the code for functions to the struct nodo, but I don't know why I get this error.

@CoolGuy I just wrote it to avoid warnings like `parameter argc is not used`

Comment: @DevKev , Don't write stupid code to get rid of warnings.If you want to get rid of "variable not used warnings",just remove the variable.In your case,change `int main(int argc, char** argv)` to `int main()` or `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, your function `getNodo` is just a front-end for `malloc`. Itreturns a new, but uninitialised node, whose members are likely to contain garbage. When you dereference `aux2->person` in `attAtEnd`:

```
aux2->person->edad=age;
```

you'll get a segmentation fault. You must not only allocate, but also populate your node, i.e. fill it wie sensible data. (That data could also mean that `aux2->person == NULL`, but if that is valid, you should check it before dereferencing the pointer.)

Apart from the strange mix of Spanish and Englis, your function is not well named: `get` suggests that you are trying to access existing memory. Your function should probably be named something like `newNode` or `crearNodo`.